# Ensemble learning, multiple classifier system

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to use a MCS (Multi classifier system) to do some better work on limited data i.e become more accurate.

I am using K-means clustering at the moment but may choose to go with FCM (Fuzzy c-means) with that the data is clustered into groups (clusters) the data could represent anything, colours for example. I first cluster the data after pre-processing and normalization and get some distinct clusters with a lot in between. I then go on to use the clusters as the data for a Bayes classifier, each cluster represents a distinct colour and the Bayes classifier is trained and the data from the clusters is then put through separate Bayes classifiers. Each Bayes classifier is trained only in one colour. If we take the colour spectrum 3 - 10 as being blue 13 - 20 as being red and the spectrum in between 0 - 3 being white up to 1.5 then turning blue gradually through 1.5 - 3 and same for blue to red.

What I would like to know is how or what kind of aggregation method (if that is what you would use) could be applied so that the Bayes classifier can become stronger, and how does it work? Does the aggregation method already know the answer or would it be human interaction that corrects the outputs and then those answers go back into the Bayes training data? Or a combination of both? Looking at Bootstrap aggregating it involves having each model in the ensemble vote with equal weight so not quite sure in this particular instance I would use bagging as my aggregation method? Boosting however involves incrementally building an ensemble by training each new model instance to emphasize the training instances that previous models mis-classified, not sure if this would be a better alternative to bagging as im unsure how it incrementally builds upon new instances? And the last one would be Bayesian model averaging which is an ensemble technique that seeks to approximate the Bayes Optimal Classifier by sampling hypotheses from the hypothesis space, and combining them using Bayes' law, however completely unsure how you would sample hypotheses from search space?

I know that usualy you would use a competitive approach to bounce between the two classification algorithms one says yes one says maybe a weighting could be applied and if its correct you get the best of both classifiers but for keep sake I dont want a competitive approach.

Another question is using these two methods together in such a way would it be beneficial, i know the example i provided is very primitive and may not apply in that example but can it be beneficial in more complex data.

**EDIT**

I was told this may be a better place to ask this question from Stack overflow, original question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536786/ensemble-learning-multiple-classifier-system

Comment: I do know that it is a bit late, yet I wonder: Did you use the output of k-means clustering as labels for your Bayesian classifier? If you initialize the k-means clustering randomly (which is mostly done), then your labels are not stable. Today you would probably chose to use Random Forest as an ensemble classifier. If you found an answer, please answer your question yourself.